# Combine / Merge CSS files like normalize.css and main.css without overriding elements

Tags: html, css

When using the default normalize.css stylesheet you include it before your main.css (or whatever you call your custom stylesheet) and then everything that has been declarated gets overridden.

This is a very common way, but is it possible to combine / merge them so that you don't have double declarations?

Example:

body tag in normalize.css has the properties "margin: 0".

body tag in main.css has "margin: 10px", so the normalize.css gets overridden and the main.css is used.

There must be some kind of tool or something that checks for multiple declarations and removes unnecessary ones.

I know it's possible to customize the normalize.css directly, but for development I think it would be way more easier to have tool automatically check if anything can be left out.